# Implementation Of Resolution Refutation In SML

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to implement resolution refutation for predicate logic to verify if a set of clauses form a logical consequence of a given set of antecedent clauses. I need to code this in SML. Can someone help me to get started ?? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Larry Paulson is best known as pioneer and grand master of theorem prover implementation in SML in the 1980-ies and 1990-ies.  His classic text book "ML for the Working Programmer" has a tactical prover in chapter 10 as full worked example.  You can get the ML sources from [ML book](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/) without buying the book.

This assumes an educational background for this question.  If you want a real system you should take Isabelle from today (2013).